# Basic Bayes theorem question

Tags: bayesian

What is the difference between "probability of H given E" as calculated by Bayes theorem and the "positive predictive value" of E?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, those two are pretty unrelated.

Probability of H given E is simply the probability that the event H will happen when we already know that the event E happened.

On the other hand, when we do a [statistical inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_inference) (that is, draw conclusions about population using a sample of it), we often want to know if something like the mean of a variable is zero.

We might do a test and come to the conclusion that it's indeed zero. However, we are never 100% sure, and we might have told that it's zero, but it's not, whenever this happens we have a false alarm. `1-(proportion of false alarms)` gives you the positive predictive value, that is the proportion of times we don't have a false alarm in our test.